# Why is my material black after using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry

[image]Hello I'm not sure when my material went black, but it is showing in the preview in the right panel. If anyone can help me figure out why this is doing this, it would be much appreciated. Thank you sm, I will leave my file and a screenshot down below. The object is basing the color off of the emission.

Comment: You need to use a _Set Material_ node, and pick your material in the node.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett hey chris, thank you yes i tried doing this and it just changed my droplets to black as well. i noticed my transform node that's connected to my instance on "instances on points" is what is making it black.

Comment: try realize instances before set material

Comment: @Chris yes i tried this as well, nothing seems to work. im putting the node everywhere and its still just black. i may try to redo everything, but just now sure why.

Comment: ok, then pls provide blend file, don't forget to file->external data -> pack resources before uploading, you can upload here: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l614fi3wtufsma5/can%20blend.blend?dl=0               i can only post it as a dropbox file bc its not packing correctly and my file is too large, but it is there, i really hope you can help. thank you sm

Comment: @Chris attached the file through Dropbox thank you again

Comment: Have you made sure to use the UVmap node to set the right UVMap? You cannot use a standard Texture Coordinate Node to properly map textures set from Geometry nodes.

Comment: @Callmepro this could definitely be an issue! I will try it thank you sm

Answer (score 1):

Removing the *Realize Instances* node altogether seems to work to remove the black, but I'm not sure that's the end result you're going for. By removing that node, then adding a new glass material and assigning that to the drops via "set material", it gives a rather convincing look, regardless:

[image: Can]

Comment: Omgg thank you so much!!!  yes this is what I was going for